# Woocommerce Category pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to make an online shop using WordPress WooCommerce plugin with the  Virtue theme(http://www.kadencethemes.com/product/virtue-free-theme/).

I got stuck, I need to make 3 categories for the products, made 3 sub-pages for the 3 categories and entered the short code to show the corresponding category

```
[product_category category="medical"]
```

WooCommerce asked for the page that will contain the products "Product" so he added all the elements there with pagination and sorting options. I would like to have the same options for my  subcategories.

So for i think the Virtue theme uses the "archive-product.php" in its WooCommerce folder. But how do i use that same code for my other Pages?

For better picture of my situation uploaded the website to a temporary server.
http://host.quadom.com

Comment: WooCommerce will use it's standard product loop on category shortcodes so it should work as is just by putting the shortcode in your page - have you got a URL where we can see what's happening?

Comment: http://host.quadom.com/shop/ vs http://host.quadom.com/shop/medical/ the second link is  a page that has the shortcode, and it doeas not do the pagination  (i removed the sorting option from the main shop)

Comment: Looking at your main shop page, if I click on a product and then click on that product's category within that single product page, it's giving me a 404 error (for the nutrition one anyway) - You obviously have a problem with your product categories. Have you made any custom changes to the template files at all?